# Donut chart in highcharts appears messed up on export

Tags: highcharts

We are using highcharts as our charting library. It's great and exporting works well in all scenarios except one. We have a donut chart with two levels. When it is rendered in the browser it shows up fine:

[image: in browser]

If you now export this chart using the default highcharts service it shows a bit like this:
[image: exported image]

Anyone know why this is happening and if there is any way we can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake in the configuration was when I was dynamically updating the colour:

```
chart.series[0].data[s].update({color: "#FFFFFF")}, false);
```

This didn't just mean I was updating the color but also the whole point. This meant that by running the above I was running y to nothing! Although the chart displayed ok the data sent to the exporting service was with unset values for the slices.. hence the empty slices in the chart. to fix it I had to do something like:

```
chart.series[0].data[s].update({
              color: "#FFFFFF",
              y: chart.series[0].data[s].y,
              name: chart.series[0].data[s].name,
)}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to finalize the question, you may now mark your own answer as accepted :)

Comment: I'm only allowed to do so in 2 days:) but will do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a fiddle of your problem, and emailing HighCharts support about it (or link the fiddle here), they are very helpful and usually respond quickly.

Your problem does however seem to be related to your code as I also generate and export donut charts with no problems

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue in a js fiddle. You are right under normal configuration donut charts are fine. The issue seems to be calling chart.redraw()... I have to figure a way around this because unfortunately I need to redraw the chart for my colouring to work (i set the colours dynamically). Thanks for your response though!

Comment: sounds like you identified your problem, no problem. :)